# Angular 1.2: animate model change / enter new, leave old

Tags: angularjs, animation, ng-animate

I'm trying to archieve an animation when the value of a model changes. Depenpending on the new value larger or smaller then the previous the animation should change its direction.

But mainly i'm after the effect of the old value fading out and the new fading in.

```
app.directive('animateValue', function($animate) {
    return {
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {

          // set up container for old and new elements
          var newElement = angular.element('<div class="new">new</div>');
          var oldElement = angular.element('<div class="old">old</div>');

          // append them to the element
          element.append(newElement)
          element.append(oldElement);

          scope.$watch('value', function(newval, oldval) {

            // fill elements with new content
            oldElement.text(oldval)
            newElement.text(newval);

            // whatever happens – old value should leave, new should enter
            $animate.leave(oldElement)
            $animate.enter(newElement, element);

            // set class depending on direction
            if (newval > oldval) {
              $animate.setClass(element, 'ani-up', 'ani-down');
            } else {
              $animate.setClass(element, 'ani-down', 'ani-up');
            }

          });
        }
    };
});
```

I also set up a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gm1Sk7kPo2yrN9UZCslP

Unfortunately i have little idea, how to fade out the old value. The element i set up for this is not showing up at all...

Comment: I found some code on plunkr that had lots of what i'm searching for already in. Forked it, modified it and I have it roughly running. For reference if some other user has the same problem to solve: [link](http://embed.plnkr.co/ZrB2IJ6gaSNhoPORxWl7/preview)